# Check which drawable is set in a view in Android

Tags: java, android, drawable

I'm trying to check which drawable is set to a View in Android with an if statement as below

```
if (v.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.emptyhour)))
        {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fullhour);
            Log.d("cell id: ", String.valueOf(v.getId()));
        }
```

It seems something is wrong cause it doesn't find anything.

Before this I was using:

```
if (v.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.emptyhour).getConstantState()))
        {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fullhour);
            Log.d("cell id: ", String.valueOf(v.getId()));
        }
```

But `getDrawable(int)` is deprecated as API 22.

Any help please or any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I find this to be the best solution for checking drawable with the imageResource:

```
public static boolean checkImageResource(Context ctx, ImageView imageView,
        int imageResource) {
    boolean result = false;

    if (ctx != null && imageView != null && imageView.getDrawable() != null) {
        ConstantState constantState;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            constantState = ctx.getResources()
                    .getDrawable(imageResource, ctx.getTheme())
                    .getConstantState();
        } else {
            constantState = ctx.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource)
                    .getConstantState();
        }

        if (imageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == constantState) {
            result = true;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I need it for a view or a TextView, TextView has no method getDrawable()